# How do I manage my array of children components' states?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm new to react, so forgive me. I'm having a problem understanding states, specifically those of children.

**Purpose**: I'm trying to create a form that a user can append more and more components -- in this case, images.

**What happens**: User appends 2 or more images. User tries to upload an image with `UploadButton` component, but both the images are the same. I believe this has to do with both appended children sharing the same state.

**Question**: How do I give each appended child its own image without affecting the other appended children?

```
class Page extends Component
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      id: '', 
      numChildren: 0,
      images: [],
    }
    this.onAddChild = this.onAddChild.bind(this);
  }

  showModal() {
    this.setState({
      numChildren: 0,
      images: [],
    });
  }

  renderModal() 
    const children = [];
    //Here's my array of child components
    for(var i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i += 1) {
        children.push(<this.ChildComponent key={i} />);
    }

    return (
      <ReactModal>
        <this.ParentComponent addChild={this.onAddChild}>
          {children}
        </this.ParentComponent>
      </ReactModal>
    )
  }

  onAddChild = () => {
    this.setState({
      numChildren: this.state.numChildren + 1
    })
  }

  ParentComponent = (props) => (
    <div>
      {props.children}
      <Button onClick={props.addChild}>Add Item</Button>
    </div>
  );

  ChildComponent = () => (
    <div>
      <UploadButton
        storage="menus"
        value={this.state.images}
        onUploadComplete={uri => this.setState({images: uri})}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's the code for `UploadButton`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import uuid from 'uuid';
import firebase from '../config/firebase';

class UploadButton extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isUploading: false
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    const input = document.createElement("INPUT");
    input.setAttribute("type", "file");
    input.setAttribute("accept", "image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png");
    input.addEventListener("change", ({target: {files: [file]}}) => this.uploadFile(file));
    input.click();
  }

  uploadFile(file) {
    console.log('F', file);
    const id = uuid.v4();
    this.setState({ isUploading: true })
    const metadata = {
      contentType: file.type
    };
    firebase.storage()
      .ref('friends')
      .child(id)
      .put(file, metadata)
      .then(({ downloadURL }) => {
        this.setState({ isUploading: false })
        console.log('Uploaded', downloadURL);
        this.props.onUploadComplete(downloadURL);
      })
      .catch(e => this.setState({ isUploading: false }));

  }

  render() {
    const { 
      props: {
        value,
        style = {},
        className = "image-upload-button",
      },
      state: {
        isUploading    
      }
    } = this;

    return (
      <div 
        onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
        className={className}
        style={{
          ...style,
          backgroundImage: `url("${this.props.value}")`,          
        }}>
        {isUploading ? "UPLOADING..." : !value ? 'No image' : ''}
      </div>
    );
  }

}


export default UploadButton;
```

*I tried to exclude all unnecessary code not pertaining to my problem, but please, let me know if I need to show more.*

EDIT: This is my attempt, it doesn't work:

```js
//altered my children array to include a new prop
renderModal() {
  const children = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i += 1) {
    children.push(<this.ChildComponent imageSelect={this.onImageSelect} key={i} />);
  }
  //...
};

//my attempt to assign value and pass selected image back to images array
ChildComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <UploadButton
        storage="menus"
        value={uri => this.props.onImageSelect(uri)} //my greenness is really apparent here
        onUploadComplete={uri => this.setState({images: uri})}
    /> 
    //...
  </div>
);

//added this function to the class
onImageSelect(uri) {
  var el = this.state.images.concat(uri);
  this.setState({
    images: el
  })
}
```

I know I'm not accessing the child prop correctly. This is the most complexity I've dealt with so far. Thanks for your time.

Comment: TLDR Have you considered keeping all images in the parent in an array and iterating through it to create the children.

Comment: @Miro J. I've thought that an array of images somewhere, either `constructor` or `ParentComponent`,  would be a solution. I'm not sure how to go about it: user clicks `UploadButton`, the selected image gets put into an image array, then iterating through the array creates all the children. Currently, the user appends the children *before* selecting the images. I heard somewhere that programmers spend 90% of their time, not typing, but thinking of how to implement their ideas while staring at the computer screen and I'm experiencing that for three days now.

Comment: Google "how to call a parent function from a child component in react" > Create a function in the child for transferring the image to the parent after uploading finishes. The parent array should have a maximum of one "empty" element, which will show the upload functionality in the child.

Comment: @Miro J. I'm trying to implement what you suggested now. I have a feeling part of the problem is because I'm using stateless components, so editing a lot of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `this.state` in Child / Parent component, you are actually accessing the state of Page. Now, I would recommend that you pass in the index of the child to the Child like so

`children.push(<this.ChildComponent key={i} index={i}/>)`

so that each children deals with only its own image like so

```
ChildComponent = ({index}) => (
    <div>
      <UploadButton
        storage="menus"
        value={this.state.images[index]}
        onUploadComplete={uri => {
          let images = this.state.images.slice()
          images[index] = uri
          this.setState({images})
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: YES! This was exactly the answer I was looking for! Thank you so much!